# Plotly- bring x axis to the front

Tags: plotly

I am trying to create a plotly scatter chart.  But the shading goes above the x axis line. I've tried fig.update_xaxes(layer='above traces') but this does not seem to do anything. Any help would be appreciative.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.offline as py

np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({'values':np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=10, size=30)})

fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(
    x=df.index,
    y=df['values'],
))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=[20,20], x=[0,30], fill='tonexty'))
fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(zeroline=True, zerolinewidth=2, zerolinecolor='black'), plot_bgcolor='white', xaxis=dict(zeroline=True, zerolinewidth=2, zerolinecolor='black', layer='above traces'))

py.plot(fig)
```

[image: Picture of graph here]

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example of your code that you used to generate your current scatter plot with the shading? It will be much less time consuming for people on stackoverflow if we have a code sample to start with, so we can see what you have tried, and so that we don't have to try to recreate your problem from scratch... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an annotation to create your xaxis in the middle of the yaxis, then you can add the shaded region as another annotation and specify `layer="below"`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({'values':np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=10, size=30)})

fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(
    x=df.index,
    y=df['values'], 
))

## add shape that covers some of the data
## specify the layer below
fig.add_shape(type="rect",
    x0=1, y0=-10, x1=10, y1=10,
    line=dict(
        color="Gray",
        width=2,
    ),
    fillcolor="LightGray",
    layer="below"
)

fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(showline=True, linecolor="black", linewidth=2))

## add xaxis using horizontal line annotation
fig.add_hline(y=0)

fig.show()
```

[image]